# change object into array present another component in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

i am sorry for the very basic question as i m new to react js. i have created an array in a react component and render it through map function in one component and i want to change (add/Subject) in the array from an other component on basis of _id. the following is a sample that helps you better to understand what i actually want. Thanks in advance Sir

```
    {*Array Component*}
const ArrayData =[
    {
        _id:1,
        title:"All Searches"
    },
    {
        _id:5,
        title:1
    },
    {
        _id:6,
        title:"4"
    }
]
export default ArrayData;

{*2nd Component*}

import react from "react"
import ArrayData from ArrayComponent
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ArrayData:ArrayData,
            collapsed: false,
        }
}
render() {
        const { ArrayData } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
               <FirstChild Data={ArrayData} />
               <SecondChild />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
!------------------------------------------!

{*FirstChild*}

class FirstChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state={
            ArrayData:props.ArrayData
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { ArrayData} = this.state;
        const renderArray = ArrayData.slice(0, 5).map(Object => {
            return <h1>{object._id} </h1>
        })
        return (
            <>
              {renderArray}
            </>
        );

    }
}

export default FirstChild;


!-----------------------------------------!

{*SecondChild*}

import { React } from "react";
const SecondChild = () => {

    const handleUpdate=(_id, Title) =>{

        {*function that can add the inputs as a object into that arrayComponent*}

    }
    const handleDelete=(_id) =>{

        {*function that can delete a object from that arrayComponent having the id given by User in the feild*}

    }

    return (
        <>
                    <input type='text' name='_id' placeHolder="Which object you want to delete" />
                    <button type=Submit onClick={handleDelete} >Delete</button>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type='text' name='_id' />
                    <input type='text' name='title' />
                    <button type=Submit onClick={handleUpdate} >Update</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default SecondChild;
```

Comment: what does `change` means, Do you want to perform CRUD operation on the `ArrayData` array.

Comment: What exactly is a subject? Are they objects inside `ArrayData`?

Comment: You haven't passed the `tabsData` from the `Parent` component. So how could you get in the `child` component? Please make it specific what you want to do and what you've tried.

Comment: sorry that was by mistake

Comment: I need to add new item to my array when needed and delete the item containing specific id from that same array, like if user add data it should add that data it to that array as one more object (3 before and now 4 objects in that array) and user want to delete the item having specific id then it delete that object from the array which have that id

Answer (score 0):

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-albattani-ej5wn?file=/src/components/SecondChild.js:0-1061)

All you need to do is declare `handleDelete` and `handleUpdate` on the `Parent` component and pass it as a `props` in `SecondChild` component. If we place *state* and its *methods* in `Parent` component, then it is easy to track, debug, and easy to maintain. It would be easy to pass the methods if we define another component, let say `ThirdComponent` and it also contains functionality to perform CRUD operation on the `ArrayData` array.

In the `FirstChild` component, you were destructuring the ArrayData `const { ArrayData} = this.state;` and using it in the render method. It won't update we receive new `props` because you are rendering the array state that gets created once(as a constructor will get called once) and we want the latest value of `ArrayData` from the parent component. We can use props directly in the `render` method. You need to see the react [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) methods.

**Parent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ArrayData from "./ArrayComponent";
import FirstChild from "./FirstChild";
import SecondChild from "./SecondChild";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ArrayData: ArrayData,
      collapsed: false
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete(id) {
    const idToDelete = parseInt(id, 10);

    this.setState((state) => {
      const filteredArrayData = state.ArrayData.filter(
        (el) => el._id !== idToDelete
      );
      return {
        ArrayData: filteredArrayData
      };
    });
  }

  handleUpdate(newObj) {
    console.log(newObj);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ArrayData: [...state.ArrayData, newObj]
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FirstChild Data={this.state.ArrayData} />
        <SecondChild
          handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
          handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

**FirstChild.js**

```
import React from "react";

class FirstChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.Data.slice(0, 5).map((el) => {
          return <h1 key={el._id}>{el._id}</h1>;
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default FirstChild;
```

**SecondChild.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const SecondChild = ({ handleUpdate, handleDelete }) => {
  const [idToDelete, setIdToDelete] = useState(null);
  const [newID, setNewID] = useState(null);
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        name="_id"
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setIdToDelete(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Which object you want to delete"
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={() => handleDelete(idToDelete)}>
        Delete
      </button>

      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>

      <input
        type="text"
        name="_id"
        placeholder="id"
        onChange={(e) => setNewID(e.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        name="title"
        placeholder="title"
        onChange={(e) => setNewTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => handleUpdate({ _id: newID, title: newTitle })}
      >
        Update
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default SecondChild;
```